# Heroku how to run as other custom environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to use postgres on Heroku, and use mysql on my server.

I added a "pg" environment to my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'baidu_push'
gem 'geokit', github: 'TangMonk/geokit', branch: 'master'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'
    gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
    gem 'byebug', '~> 2.5.0'
end

group :production do
    gem 'mysql2'
end

group :pg do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable to any environment you want:

```
heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=test
```

Comment: Can I run ```heroku run RAILS_ENV=pg rails s``` instead of ```heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=pg```?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want a `pg` group but rather a group w/ the same name as your heroku `RAILS_ENV` value. So if you've run `heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=staging` you'd want to create a group called `:staging` and put the `pg` gem inside of it.